# Has anyone used Flex SDK 3.4/3.5 with the new Flash Builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I heard it can be done, but would like to hear if anyone has imported a Flex 3.4/5 project to Flash Builder 4 and kept it working targeting the 3.4/5 sdk and releasing/debugging with Flash Player 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it on 95% of my projects.  You just need to install the 3.X libraries in your Flash Builder. In your Project Properties go to Flex Library Compiler, and under Flex SDK Version you can hit 'Configure Flex SDKs..." and add them there.

The debugger depends on your flash version installed.  You can download all the old versions of flash debug ver. on the flash website.  Just install the version of Debug Player 9 that you want to run on.